# Yarn add new packages without update other packages

Tags: javascript, react-native, yarnpkg, package-managers

How do I `yarn add` without update other packages?

When I use `yarn add react-native-charts-wrapper` this command also updates my other packages.

But I don't want to update other packages.

Comment: are you sure? yarn add will only install this package and update yarn.lock and package.json file.

Comment: Yes i'm sure @shubham-gupta

Comment: what is the yarn version ?

Comment: yarn version v1.9.4 @ShubhamGupta

Comment: Agreed, tried and facing this issue. Tested with lodash and axios, installed lodash when package json contained axios and axios got updated.

Comment: @MahdiBashirpour have you, in the past, manually edited your dependencies in `package.json`? If so, this would explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It seems someone or you were modified your package.json's dependencies manually like: change version of package by hand or etc...

You can fix this by deleting yarn.lock and type `yarn install`  (installs all packages on package.json)